# Stack row values by index base R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
dat1 <- read.table(text = "row variable value
1 base 0.002
2 base 0.002
3 base 0.005
4 base 0.01
1 ate 0.00007
2 ate 0.0012
3 ate 0.003
4 ate 0.007", header = TRUE)
```

And I would like to make a barchart that has the base + ate value grouped by row index. So the resulting barplot would have four bars where the value is base + ate but I would like the ate segment to be in another color. I have it in ggplot:

```
ggplot(dat1, aes(x = row, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("\nNtile") +
  ylab("Estimate\n") +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

Can it be done in base R barplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option in `base R` is to reshape with `xtabs` into a `matrix` and then apply `barplot`

```
barplot(xtabs(value ~  variable + row, dat1), col = c('red', 'blue'))
```

-output

[image]